# Where to install Aldryn-boilerplates?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, boilerplate

The question is where should I install `Aldryn-boilerplates framework`?
I've created `virtualenv` called `env`, after that activated it.
 
But what now? Should I install that framework inside my project directory? Or it is OK to place it in root dir - `/home/stp`.
Need your advice.

Comment: Python will take care of the installation for you. Simply type `pip install aldryn-boilerplates` once you have activated the virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks alot, I'll try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pip inside your virtualenv, for easier dependencies management